# How to get the tuple which contains nearest tuple to a given tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples:

```
x = [('abc', (7, 1, 8, 41), None), ('efg', (12, 2, 13, 42), None)]
element = (13, 2, 14, 78)
```

I need to fetch the tuple that has the tuple which is nearest to the 'element'.
i.e I need to get the answer as **('efg', (12, 2, 13, 42), None)** for element = **(13,2,14,78)**

How can I do this in python?

Comment: This would entirely depend on what you mean by nearest. Are these points in space or do you want the tuple with the most terms in common. What would (12, 1, 8, 41) be closer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. Let take step by step to clear your question.

It is **count** the **matches** by 2 **tuple** and get the **max**.

```
maxCount = 0
index = 0
for i,item in enumerate(x):
  count = 0
  for a in element:
    if a in item[1]:
      count+=1
  if maxCount < count:
    index = i

print(x[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to get the symmetric differences of the sets of `ele & i[1] for i in x`.  We could make a tuple with each new `set` and the index of `x` it came from. From here we could then sort the new `set` by `len` and take the index part of are tuple with the `set with the smallest`len`which is also the least different, and plug that into`x`

```
res = [(set(element) ^ set(i[1]), x.index(i)) for i in x]
res = sorted(res, key=lambda x: len(x[0]))
# ('efg', (12, 2, 13, 42), None)
```